# Unable to find gitlab "admin/runners" page to register a shared runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab CE & not EE .

I want to register a shared runner . But when I am on this page . It doesn't allow to add any [image]

I would want to add any of the Available shared Runners . It wont let me add

Also on reading the document for Gitlab EE . It asks to do that in "admin/setting" page which is also missing in CE

Kindly help me use one of the Available shared Runners .